# $.ajax call node js equivalent?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I am not very familiar with Node js and as well as dealing with http requests so pardon me if this is something obvious.

I am following the examples on this [website](https://wit.ai/docs/http/20160526):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://api.wit.ai/message',
  data: {
    'q': 'set an alarm in 10min',
    'access_token' : 'MY_WIT_TOKEN'
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  method: 'GET',
  success: function(response) {
      console.log("success!", response);
  }
});
```

I am trying to create the equivalent of this but in Node Js. I attempted to use 'node request' however my code is not working. I have attempted a lot of variations of this but to no avail.

Here is an example:

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://api.wit.ai/message';

var data = {
    'q': 'hello test123 trying to get entities from this message',
    'access_token': 'MY_WIT_TOKEN'
};

request.get({ url: url, formData: data }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('post failed:', err);
    }

    console.log('Get successful!  Server responded with:', body);
});
```

When I compile this code, my terminal replies with:

Something went wrong. We've been notified.

Comment: You'd better refer to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone interested here is the answer using node request that worked for me.

```
var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer <WIT_TOKEN>'
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.wit.ai/message?v=20160607&q=hello',
    headers: headers
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body);
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [http](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html):

```
var http = require('http');

http.get({
    host: 'api.wit.ai',
    path: '/message'
}, function(response) {

    var body = '';

    // get all data from the stream
    response.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
    });

    response.on('end', function() {
        // all data received
       console.log(body)
    });
});
```

Comment: The request module that the OP is already using is a higher level and simpler to use module for plain http requests.  So, not sure why you're suggesting they back up the just the http module.  It can work fine, but requires more code and has fewer features.